# Using Qt::UserRole and Qt::DisplayRole for Items in QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcombobox

I am new to C++ Qt. I am trying to populate a QComboBox with values different than the values that need to be used.
For example, QComboBox shows name of devices but on selection sends the mac address of that device. I have the data.

I tried using Qt::UserRole and Qt::DisplayRole but only the values mentioned in DisplayRole are used. I think I need to define the roles? If yes, then how? Any help regarding this?

```
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
int i = 0;
for (auto info : list)
{
    if (info.validateMACAddress())
    {
        memData->comboBox->addItem(info.getMacAddress().arg(i));
        memData->comboBox->setItemData(i, info.getDeviceName(), Qt::DisplayRole);
        memData->comboBox->setItemData(i, info.getMacAddress(), Qt::UserRole + 1);
        i++;
    }
}
memData->comboBox->setModel(model);
```

Comment: You could explain what your problem is. Do not you know how to get the MAC? remove `memData->comboBox->setModel(model);` and `QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(this);`

Comment: The problem is that device name is sent when I choose a device not mac address

Comment: In other words, do you want to get the getMacAddress information in the slot that is connected to the QComboBox?

Comment: Yes, and it would be nice if I can do that without changing any other code.

Comment: you could show the connection and slot code

Comment: You can get it by using `currentData` `memData->comboBox->currentData(Qt::UserRole + 1);`

Comment: I need to look into it, it is a long code, I will share code snippets after I get something useful out of it @eyllanesc

Comment: @Simon and where to use this?

Comment: @ArchitJ in the slot because you want to get the information there...

Comment: @eyllanesc I will look into the slot code and get back to you. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to establish a model since QComboBox has an internal model. Also `memData->comboBox->setItemData (i, text, Qt::DisplayRole);` is equivalent to `memData->comboBox->addItem(text);` so just place one of them.

```
int i = 0;
for (auto info : list){
    if (info.validateMACAddress()){
        memData->comboBox->addItem(info.getMacAddress().arg(i));
        memData->comboBox->setItemData(i, info.getMacAddress(), Qt::UserRole + 1);
        i++;
    }
}
```

And to get the mac you should use the `currentData()` method in the slot:

```
// Slot:

auto mac = memData->comboBox->currentData(Qt::UserRole + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks man, so i tried this in the slot. I had to define the case for my code and do the adding parameters and stuff and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `currentIndexChanged` signal

One option is to use labmda.

```
connect(memData->comboBox, QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged),
    [=](int index)
    { 
         // get mac address
         auto oMacAddress = memData->comboBox->itemData(index, Qt::UserRole +1);

    });
```

Or add slot to your class

```
 connect(memData->comboBox, QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged),
        this, &MyClass::HandleIndexChanged);

void MyClass::HandleIndexChanged(int index)
{
  // get mac address
  auto oMacAddress = memData->comboBox->itemData(index, Qt::UserRole +1);

}
```